# fcm xmpp protocal "delivery_receipt_requested" param

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

I use fcm xmpp protocol send push and Receive delivery receipt。
but starting from 2019-12-18, delivery receipts have begun to decrease, and 2019-12-20 there are no receipts at all，

I don't know why. my params no change. it's my param.

```
<message id='q2fcQ-183429'><gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">
{
  "delivery_receipt_requested": true,
  "notification": {
    "sound": "default",
    "tag": "1",
    "title": "title",
    "body": "body",
    "click_action": "push.welcome",
    "android_channel_id": "notification.default"
  },
  "time_to_live": 600,
  "message_id": "02b16456eba3483782fc471e3dd2cf73",
  "to": "xxxxxxxxxxx"
}
</gcm></message>
```

Comment: It is important to ask a clear and carefully thought-out question: this will enable other to help you.  If you are trying to solve a problem, provide the context of the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also ran into this problem 2019-12-20. Firebase stopped notifying delivery of notifications by the flag "delivery_receipt_requested".

See updates from 12/17/2016 FCM:
FCM has removed ongoing support for delivery reciepts via the XMPP protocol. In place of XMPP delivery receipts, developers should enable delivery data export in the FCM client SDK.
https://firebase.google.com/support/releases

Also, Cloud Messaging version 20.1.0 - https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#messaging_v20-1-0
Added setDeliveryMetricsExportToBigQuery(boolean) and deliveryMetricsExportToBigQueryEnabled() to control and query if messsage delivery metrics are exported to BigQuery.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to recieve notification from BigQuery in live mode? I found some analytics in BigQuery, but no information about this feature. So no real substition for delivery_receipt_requested?